# C# - SelectNode Return Null in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

I'm trying to get some information from an Instagram profile.
I generated XPath with Google Chrome

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div[1]/div
```

But , nothing is found .
I can find only up

```
  //*[@id="react-root"]
```

which is a `**<span>**`

Nothing more is located , is there any reason? Am I doing something wrong?

```
var baseURL = "https://www.instagram.com/";

var client = new HtmlWeb();


var paginaPerfil = client.Load(baseURL + "belalao");


var nos = paginaPerfil.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div/div[1]/div");
            var quantidade = nos == null ? 0 : nos.Count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment in time, https://www.instagram.com/belalao has an empty `<span id="react-root"></span>`, so your code is working as expected. Perhaps you're expecting the JavaScript which will populate the DOM with the React components will have executed, but HtmlAgilityPack will only analyze the *initial* HTML you downloaded, not execute JavaScript and analyze afterward.

View source on the page (not the same as using the DOM inspector), and you'll see what it's seeing.

Comment: damn truth. I understand now.
And is there any way to get the HTML code after the execution of JavaScript?

Comment: You can try using a headless browser like PhantomJS. I'm not sure if React is compatible with that or not.